# Why can we assume a certain term is $0$ in this case?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

So, my differential equations book tries to guide us through the process of solving Airy's equation.

We start off with

$$y''-xy=0\space,\space -\infty<x<\infty$$

The book has already explained that:
$$y''=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n$$

Hence, it is easy enough to come up with this equation:

$$(2)(1)a_2+ \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}x^n$$

However the very next thing the book says is: *Again, for this equation ot be satisfied for all x in some interval, the coefficients of like powers of x must be equal; hence $a_2=0$....*

Wait, what?

This makes sense **if and only if** $a_2$ does, indeed, equal zero.  However, my question is: what basis do we have for making this assumption?

Answer (score 1):

The key phrase here is "for this equation to be satisfied for all x in some interval, the coefficients of like powers of x must be equal."  In particular, this is true for the $x^{0}$ constant terms.

On the right hand side of this equation,

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n-1}x^{n}$

has a constant term of 0.

On the left hand side of the equation, the constant term is

$(2)(1)a_{2}+(2)(1)a_{2}$ or $4a_{2}$.

Thus $4a_{2}=0$, and $a_{2}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing coefficients of the constant term, one can get that $2\times 1\times a_2+2\times 1\times a_2=0$. Hence, $a_2=0$.